# jQuery GridView similar to Ext JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, twitter-bootstrap, datagrid

I am currently using the GridView from Ext JS in one project and it is very feature-rich and complete.

However, I am looking for something functionally equivalent for another project. Something lighter-weight and most importantly has a more spacious and customizable appearance. Perhaps something that works with Twitter Bootstrap.

By "functionally equivalent" I mean: server-side paging, column sorting and search, interface via JSON over Ajax, column-width dragging, custom data formatting functions.

By "spacious and customizable appearance" I mean to produce table layouts with big clear rows similar to [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables) or modern [Admin Themes](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/table_managed.html).

I'm happy to use anything jQuery based, but want to avoid dependencies on big UI libraries like jQuery UI or Sencha's Ext JS.

Comment: Awesome! Both SlickGrid and DataTables seem like they will fit the bill nicely. DataTables licensed "under two licenses: GPL v2 license or a BSD (3-point) license" and SlickGrid is under the MIT license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this one: http://datatables.net/index

There is an example for styling with bootstrap (http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap), but you can easily customize the appearance.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I chose DataTables because it is very mature and used in a lot of projects and admin themes. I like the author's very clear instructions on how to use with Bootstrap. The updated Bootstrap2 instructions are here:
http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2

Answer (score 1):

if you want to render so many rows and columns like 10000*10000, i recommended https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid. although you think it is not needful,you can use its sorting and search.

Comment: This looks really good. I like that it's on GitHub. I found a project to specifically add Bootstrap support:
https://github.com/reebalazs/SlickGrid-bootstrap